# mysql group by select with conditional value

Tags: php, mysql, sql, group-by

In my messages table I have following rows for example,

```
|----|---------|--------------|------|
| id | user_id | message      |status|
|====|=========|==============|======|
| 1  |  2      | msgs 11      |  r   |
|----|---------|--------------|------|
| 2  |  3      | msgs 12      |  r   |
|----|---------|--------------|------|
| 3  |  2      | msgs 13      |  r   |
|----|---------|--------------|------|
| 4  |  3      | msgs 14      |  u   |
|----|---------|--------------|------|
```

Now, I need to know two things for each `user_id`

- Whether it has any status `u` or not.
- How many messages are there

For example, a query like below
    `select user_id, status,  count(*) as totalMsg from messages group by user_id`
Would brought me following rows

```
| user_id | status| totalMsg |
|=========|=======|==========|
|  2      |   r   |    2     |
|---------|-------|----------|
|  3      |   r   |    2     | 
              ^
              |------> I need this value to be 'u' because user 3 has a message u
```

My current query doesnt really gurantee that it will look for a `u` in the status column.
Is that possible to do? If so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MAX()` will work on this since `r` is the least value based on the lexicographical order.

```
SELECT  user_ID,
        MAX(status) status,
        COUNT(*) totalMsg
FROM    messages
GROUP   BY user_ID
```

Comment: followup question: are there any other values for status? if so, what will be the output if there are no status for `u` and `r`?

Comment: ah well actual values are `read` and `unread`. Looks like nice trick. need to check

Comment: One more favour... I just want to get a better title for the question so that people having same problem can find this easily. So any one please feel free to edit the title with a better one.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what if the possible values can be more than two? At least MIN/MAX wouldnt help at that time.

Comment: going back on my first comment, what will be the output if there are no status for `u` and `r`? you'll need to use `CASE` or `IF` statements.